# Rake task failing when run in cron

Tags: centos, cron

I'm using backup_fu to backup my database. In the crontab, you have this command:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/amplify/current && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env rake backup
```

*Yes, I know a backup a minute is intense, but I'm just doing it to test. I will change the interval once I get it working.*

- However, running it in cron doesn't it backup. When I check my Amazon S3 account, I don't see a .tar.gz file.
- When I SSH in, and I paste the command exactly, it backs up and I see the .tar.gz in Amazon S3.

Note:

- I'm using RVM. However, as shown in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyversionmanager/93HXhyQ68gc), if I cd into the directory, the proper ruby selection happens.
- I'm on CentOS: `Linux version 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5.028stab070.5 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Fri Sep 17 19:10:36 MSD 2010`
- I checked `/var/log/cron` and it seems that it runs: `Feb 27 00:20:01 amplify crond[1667]: (ramon) CMD (cd /var/www/amplify/current && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/rake backup)`

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this ended up becoming an RVM issue, and not a server one. I apologize. Thanks for your answers; they've helped me figure it out.

The final one that worked was:

```
cd /var/www/amplify/current && source /home/ramon/.rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails3 && RAILS_ENV=production /home/ramon/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails3/bin/rake backup &>/home/ramon/backup.log
```

The key was to use `source /home/ramon/.rvm/environments/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@rails3`.

When I asked Wayne Seguin about cd'ing into the directory and autoloading .rvmrc, he said it'll only work if:

- RVM is loaded properly as a function (type rvm | head -1)
- The .rvmrc has been trusted previously

So it seems that in cron, RVM isn't loaded properly as a function, since I've "trusted" the .rvmrc before.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the mail for the account running the cron job, output from the command should appear there and may contain clues as to the problem.

Capture the output of the command to a file add `&>/path/to/logfile` to the end of the command to find out what is happening.

Comment: Thanks. With this I was able, to pinpoint the problem to RVM, it seems. I'm still investigating further and will update you.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
/usr/bin/env rake backup
```

depends on the `PATH` containing the location of `rake`. It's the same as simply having

```
rake backup
```

The environment for `cron` is different than that for your interactive session. Change the line in your crontab to point directly to the `rake` executable:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/amplify/current && RAILS_ENV=production /path/to/rake backup
```

or set your crontab's `PATH` (within the crontab) to include it:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/path/to/where/rake/is
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `PATH` in your crontab isn't very portable I suggest you do something like this:

```
~ $ rvm env --path                                                                                                                                  
/Users/james/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

What in that file:

```
~ $ cat `rvm env --path`                                                                                                                            
export PATH ; PATH="/Users/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9...
```

So we can do this:

```
~ $ crontab -e
0 * * * * source /Users/james/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p392 && command
# or 
0 * * * * rvm use 1.9.3@myenv && source `rvm env --path` && command
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your cronjob into separate script and call it in crontab.

```
cd /var/www/amplify/current && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env rake backup
```